# python regular expression: script to change "frame_20" to "frame_0020"

Tags: python, regex

So I have a list of filenames. They are called:

```
"fgmask_frame_20.jpg","fgmask_frame_40.jpg",..."fgmask_frame_2000.jpg" etc.
```

What I want to do is to make all of the numbers 4-digit, so that if it is `frame_20` then make it `frame_0020`, and `frame_0200` instead of `frame_200` etc.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: You've got to give a try....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: @IronFist I did.. but I dont think when you ask questions you need to give a proof you tried? I dont think posting my badly attempted code would help anyone understand the question..

Comment: You will learn from your mistake...that's my point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression as follows:

```
import re

file_names = ["fgmask_frame_20.jpg", "fgmask_frame_40.jpg", "fgmask_frame_2000.jpg"]
file_names = [re.sub(r'(.*?_)(\d+)(\.jpg)', lambda x: '{}{:04}{}'.format(x.group(1), int(x.group(2)), x.group(3)), file_name) for file_name in file_names]
print file_names
```

This would give you the following output:

```
['fgmask_frame_0020.jpg', 'fgmask_frame_0040.jpg', 'fgmask_frame_2000.jpg']
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. In which part of the code are you specifying that zeros are to be added before the non-4-digit numbers?

Comment: The `{:04}` formats the number as a string with at least 4 characters,  the 0 says to pad with zeroes.